# Tensorflow SGD not learning and outperformed by local implementation

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I have tensorflow set up with the following structure:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 32, 32, 5)         140
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 32, 32, 3)         138
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 11, 11, 3)         0
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 363)               0
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 363)               132132
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 10)                3640
=================================================================
```

Training on cifar10 data.

Using SGD, the model never breaches 10% accuracy, making it *worse* than random guessing. The compile code used is below:

```
model.compile(optimizer=SGD,
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

After many epochs, the accuracy never changes:

```
Epoch 1/100
1563/1563 [==============================] - 34s 22ms/step - loss: 2.4016 - accuracy: 0.0960 - val_loss: 2.3027 - val_accuracy: 0.1007
Epoch 2/100
1563/1563 [==============================] - 33s 21ms/step - loss: 2.3027 - accuracy: 0.0958 - val_loss: 2.3026 - val_accuracy: 0.1004
Epoch 3/100
1563/1563 [==============================] - 34s 22ms/step - loss: 2.3026 - accuracy: 0.0982 - val_loss: 2.3026 - val_accuracy: 0.1008
Epoch 4/100
1563/1563 [==============================] - 33s 21ms/step - loss: 2.3026 - accuracy: 0.0971 - val_loss: 2.3025 - val_accuracy: 0.1003
Epoch 5/100
1563/1563 [==============================] - 37s 24ms/step - loss: 2.3026 - accuracy: 0.0985 - val_loss: 2.3025 - val_accuracy: 0.1006
```

However, if I use Adam as the optimiser:

```
Epoch 1/100
1563/1563 [==============================] - 31s 20ms/step - loss: 1.9048 - accuracy: 0.3525 - val_loss: 1.5429 - val_accuracy: 0.4587
Epoch 2/100
1563/1563 [==============================] - 31s 20ms/step - loss: 1.3919 - accuracy: 0.5070 - val_loss: 1.3676 - val_accuracy: 0.5231
Epoch 3/100
1563/1563 [==============================] - 31s 20ms/step - loss: 1.2187 - accuracy: 0.5726 - val_loss: 1.3393 - val_accuracy: 0.5352
Epoch 4/100
1563/1563 [==============================] - 31s 20ms/step - loss: 1.0961 - accuracy: 0.6187 - val_loss: 1.3050 - val_accuracy: 0.5563
Epoch 5/100
1563/1563 [==============================] - 31s 20ms/step - loss: 0.9806 - accuracy: 0.6582 - val_loss: 1.3215 - val_accuracy: 0.5505
```

This makes no sense, as SGD is still a valid optimiser, it shouldn't be as redundant as it is here. So I tested it on my own implementation of a CNN, which uses only SGD. In doing this, I found after training on batch sizes of only 100, for 100 iterations, the accuracy on the validation set was, on average, 31.71%. Using a similar number of actual data points, my implementation achieved roughly similar results to the Adam optimiser in tensorflow. I should also mention, I kept as much as I could between the models identical (the structure is exactly the same, and the input data is as well). SGD on tensorflows end and on mine had exactly the same learning rate with 0 momentum.

Would anyone have an explanation as to why tensorflow seems to be outperformed? Why does it seem that SGD is essentially useless when used in tensorflow, but not when implemented typically?

Answer (score 0):

Did you use activations at each layer? Try to remove softmax from last layer if you have since you use **from_logits=True**.